# Yajilin minicubes: the Poppycock, the Balderdash, the Gobbledygook

Tags: grid-deduction, three-dimensional

> These are three-dimensional yajilin puzzles. In each puzzle, the four squares depict the layers of a $4\times4\times4$ cube.
>
> - Shade some cells on each layer. The numbered cells show how many shaded cells (not including numbered cells) are in the direction of the arrow.
> - Diagonal arrows point to squares on other layers. An up-left arrow ↖ points to smaller-numbered layers, and a down-right arrow ↘ points at higher-numbered layers. For example, a down-right arrow on layer 2 points to cells in the same row and same column on layers 3 and 4.
> - Shaded cells cannot be adjacent to another shaded cell (even those on different levels). The shaded cells are allowed to touch the numbered cells, however.
> - Unshaded unnumbered cells on each layer are all connected in 2D (i.e. each layer is treated separately).
> - Make a single loop in 3D space which goes through every unshaded, unnumbered cell.
>
> [image]

Comment: darn it! this should have gotten much more votes! (the question I mean)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Maybe the next one will go viral :D

Comment: when is it? funny both of the yajilin end up hex finishing the first and me finishing the second and the third XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full Solution

No 1 (thx @hexomino)

> [image]

No 2

> [image]

No 3

> [image]

Comment: Yup, this is correct.

Comment: #2 is correct as well. You get the tick!

Answer (score 2):

Here's #1 (to add to Omega Krypton's #3)

> [image]

Comment: Small problem on level #4, otherwise looks good.

Comment: @jafe, Ah yes, my apologies, I must have hit 'undo' at the end as that was the last thing I did. Fixed now.